# How to get application name from python?

Tags: python, windows

In Wondows7 64.
I want to get application name from python.

here is code that I can get Processes name,but it's not I want.

```
from psutil import process_iter
process = filter(lambda p: p.name() == "main2.exe", process_iter())
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear and operating system specific.  Are you asking for something on Windows?  Giving an example of what you expect would help clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: In some cases the file description is displayed as the application name. Call `GetFileVersionInfoSizeEx` and `GetVersionInfoEx` to get the version info, and then `VerQueryValue` to get the file description, i.e. `\StringFileInfo\[lang-codepage]\FileDescription`, where `\VarFileInfo\Translation` has the array of available lang-codepage identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, you could make a system call:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'WMIC PROCESS get Caption'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    print line
```

You could also get the 'Commandline' or 'Processid' if the 'Caption' isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean this, which gives you the name of the Python script that is running:

```
import os
print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
```